# Why do the lights turn off when I turn off the fan portion of my newly installed ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

I installed a ceiling fan a while ago, Hunter brand. My room has two switches; one for light, one for fan. When I turn both of them on, but I just want to have the lights on, the lights go off when I flip the fan off. This is driving me bananas because I rechecked the wiring on the ceiling. Please help.

Comment: Did you check the wiring in the breakout box containing the switches?

Comment: Before the new installation, had there been a  fan that worked as you wanted? And how many wires go from the fan box to the switch box?

Comment: Can you include a diagram and/or photos of the wiring in both the ceiling, and switch box?

Answer (score 1):

If the lights don't work at all, when the fan is not on: (and assuming the incoming power goes to the switches and does not come from the ceiling)

The switch for the fan, powers the switch for the lights. Instead, the incoming power at the wall switch's J-box needs a pig-tail, to feed the two switches.

Beyond that, I'd need a detailed description (preferably pictures) of the ceiling box and wall box, noting what goes where and which ones are the incoming.